# Rule in InfoPath changing field value when it shoudn't

Tags: infopath

I have a rule in InfoPath on a SharePoint 2010 list that when the status of an Action Item is changed to Closed the Date Closed column will populate.  The problem is the Date Closed field is populating when the status is changed to In Progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Created another rule that is STATUS is not closed, Date Closed field is blank.  This allows the Date Closed field to return to empty if the status was closed in error.